# What provides the mdadm-raid boot facility?

Tags: boot, raid, 15.10, mdadm, init

Three of my initscripts depend on boot facility mdadm-raid.  In particular,

```
user@host:/etc/init.d$ grep mdadm-raid *
cryptdisks:# Should-Start:      udev mdadm-raid lvm2
cryptdisks:# Should-Stop:       udev mdadm-raid lvm2
cryptdisks-early:# Should-Start:      udev mdadm-raid
cryptdisks-early:# Should-Stop:       udev mdadm-raid
mdadm:# Required-Start:    $local_fs $syslog mdadm-raid
mdadm:# Required-Stop:     $local_fs $syslog sendsigs mdadm-raid
```

However, no init scripts provide mdadm-raid (note there are no Provides) lines in the output).  I cannot find a virtual facility called mdadm-raid in /etc/insserv.conf or under /etc/insserv.conf.d/.

Is this a bug?  Is there another place that facilities are defined?  Does anyone know exactly what mdadm-raid was supposed to represent?

The consequence of mdadm-raid having no provider is this:

```
user@host:/etc/init.d$ sudo dpkg --configure -a
<snip>
insserv: Service mdadm-raid has to be enabled to start service mdadm
insserv: exiting now!
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
dpkg: error processing package mdadm (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
<snip>
```